# Format {:%}: Add space between digit and percentage

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

Is it possible to get this output from python replacement field?

```
'{:.1%}'.format(0.4) # -> 40.0 %
```

I would like to have a space after the digit.

My current workaround is:

```
'{:.1f} %'.format(0.4 * 100)
```

Comment: I thought maybe you could use locale (https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) but it doesn't seem to have %, only $ and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) says, when you used the `%` format operator,

> it multiplies the number by 100 and displays in fixed ('f') format, followed by a percent sign.

There is no space or way to add one.

So your workaround is the solution